# module.exports/require of Map: same data but object is not a Map anymore

Tags: javascript, dictionary, module.exports

using node.js v16.15.0
I export this map from a ./constants.js file

```
const NETWORKS_LOOKUP = new Map([
    ["1", "mainnet"],
    ["3", "ropsten"],
    ["4", "rinkeyby"],    
    ["5", "goerli"],
    ["2a", "kovan"],
    ["31337", "Hardhat"]
]);
module.exports = {NETWORKS_LOOKUP}
```

in another file I use

```
const NETWORKS_LOOKUP = require("./constants.js")
```

and when I do something like this with it

```
const CONTRACT_NETWORK = "1"
console.log(NETWORKS_LOOKUP.get(CONTRACT_NETWORK))
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: NETWORKS_LOOKUP.get is not a function
```

and indeed if I do this it returns false

```
console.log(NETWORKS_LOOKUP instanceof Map)
```

So why is my map losing it's mappyness? It actually still looks like it should be a map as if I do this

```
console.log(NETWORKS_LOOKUP)
```

is produces this - it still looks like a map

```
{
  NETWORKS_LOOKUP: Map(6) {
    '1' => 'mainnet',
    '3' => 'ropsten',
    '4' => 'rinkeyby',
    '5' => 'goerli',
    '2a' => 'kovan',
    '31337' => 'Hardhat'
  }
}
```

I have used this same setup in another project, although it was a react project and using
`export {NETWORKS_LOOKUP}`; & `import { NETWORKS_LOOKUP } from './constants';`

I don't want to change my project to using `export/import` as that will give me other headaches.

I need to get it working with `module.exports` and `require` so that it's still a map and I can use `.get()` to do lookups.

Comment: ```const { NETWORKS_LOOKUP } = require("./constants.js")```

Comment: that's the answer. so easy when you know how and get the syntax right. tx

Comment: I was really pleased to have gotten an answer to this so quick so I could move on to the next thing, but thinking on it, I'm still unsure what exactly was wrong. 
I commonly see require syntax used without curly brackets, and in this case, I'm only exporting and requiring the one variable, so I'm not sure why it's the case I need curly brackets/destructuring ... and it seems bizarre that the returned object looks just like a mapping, but has been stripped of its methods. 
Any wisdom on the inner workings would be gratefully received.
points to be had If you'd like to expand to an answer

Comment: When you do `{NETWORKS_LOOKUP}` you're creating a new object literal `{}` with a literal key of `"NETWORKS_LOOKUP"` that holds the value in the variable `NETWORKS_LOOKUP`, which in your case is the `Map`. Because you've assigned this object to `module.exports`, that's the object you get when you use `require()` from that file. You could have done `const exportedObj = require(...)` and then used `exportedObj.NETWORKS_LOOKUP` to access your Map, but destructuring the Map while exporting allows you to directly put the map into a new variable (ie:  the `NETWORKS_LOOKUP` variable).